# Need a recommendation for a C++ GUI library

Tags: c++

I want to make remote administration tool. I want to take the first step by implementing the GUI or part of it (since it will be fun while being my first real experience with C++).

I need the following features in the GUI library:-
1) Modern easy-to-work-with paradigm
2) Modern kool features.
3) OS-independent. i.e. works on Mac OSx, Linux Ubuntu, and Win 7. And if could be, Android also.

Comment: What are you looking for, a networking library or a GUI library? They are completely different things.

Comment: If you find it please let us know

Comment: Dam... I changed the title in 5 seconds but got downrated before that! Anyway I want a GUI library, (I was thinking of both in my mind.)

Comment: This will start a flame, I guess. Isn't the internet full of comparisons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) ... it offers pretty much everything you need.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds to me you're looking for [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29).

Answer (score 3):

Although there are already similar answers, it cannot be said often enough: **Qt** definitely offers everything you're looking for. I highly recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://www.wxwidgets.org/ ? I've never used it in C++, but I have used the python bindings for it and found it pretty easy and very powerful. Believe they have a nice demo/sample code application for most of the features in the library too.